# Best way to import a module (.py file) into another with access to variables?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-importlib

I have a simple .py file with some variables and constants.  In my mail file I have functions which reference these variables.  I realize I can run the file with inputs first but is there a way to have it automatically load? I have tried importlib but that doesn't execute it.  It might sound silly but even when the file is run and the variables are visible my editor (Spyder) still gives me those 'undefined name" flags which drives me nuts.

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: Not sure what the exact issue is. For instance if you import a script called ````util```` with a variable ````var````, then you need to access the variables through ````util.var```` rather than ````var```` alone. Can't help further if there's no detailed description.

Comment: That was it, forgot the util.var part.  Thanks